# Fleiss' Kappa alternative for inter-rater reliability with multiple answers

Tags: binary-data, reliability, agreement-statistics

I have a dataset where researchers assign a binary yes/no answers to cells in a matrix. For each row more than one, but at least one, 'x' is allowed.

For example, researchers 1 may code:

```
0 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0
```

For four researchers the total number of counts may look like

```
0 0 1 4 4
0 0 3 0 1
4 4 4 4 0
```

**What is the best measure of inter-rater reliability?**

I believe if only one 'x' per row was allowed, Fleiss' Kappa (FK) would provide a metric. However, the sums across the row may  exceed 4 hence a naive implementation of FK is flawed.

Ideally, I can derive the measure from the count matrix above.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: you want to compare the four raters' categorical judgements. As you say, Fleiss' Kappa is the way to go. But then your data set consists of *sums* of the four raters' judgements? Why is that?

This might help: https://mlnl.net/jg/software/ira/